# Why does the whole javascript file execute even though im only exporting a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am exporting this function:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';


const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/nextauth', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

console.log('hello why is this printing');

async function database(req, res, next) {
  if (!client.isConnected()) await client.connect();
  console.log('connected');
  req.dbClient = client;
  req.db = client.db('nextauth');
  return next();
}

export default database;
```

And i am importing it here:

```
import database from '../../middlewares/database'

handler.use(database)
```

For context - This is a next js application and what you are seeing is next-connect code (basically just node js).
As you can see im only exporting the single function, So why does every line in the file execute?

Comment: Because that's how modules work. The entire module code block is evaluated. It's the way the language was designed to work.

Comment: What if it didn't execute? What would "client" inside your exported function be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file has to be executed in order for the function declaration to create the function and the `export` statement to create the export.